# Paypal API, IPN message is not received

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-ipn

with the help of this script, I'm trying to integrate the payment chained
https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php
PHP SDK for integrating with PayPal's APIs AdaptivePayments

I am still at the beginning, payment chained in sandbox works
but my listnerIPN.php not receive any notification from PayPal IPN
which can be the cause?

this is the print of curl request body params:

> requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&actionType=PAY&cancelUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fshoppaz.com%3A80%2Ftest%2Fadaptivepayments-sdk-php-master%2Fsamples%2FPay.php&currencyCode=EUR&feesPayer=SENDER&ipnNotificationUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fshoppaz.com%2Ftest%2Fadaptivepayments-sdk-php-master%2Fsamples%2FIPN%2FIPNListener.php&receiverList.receiver(0).amount=1.0&receiverList.receiver(0).email=biagiopas-business%40yahoo.it&receiverList.receiver(0).primary=false&receiverList.receiver(1).amount=1.0&receiverList.receiver(1).email=abiagiopas-business%40yahoo.it&receiverList.receiver(1).primary=false&receiverList.receiver(2).amount=1.0&receiverList.receiver(2).email=bbiagiopas-business%40yahoo.it&receiverList.receiver(2).primary=false&reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError=false&returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fshoppaz.com%3A80%2Ftest%2Fadaptivepayments-sdk-php-master%2Fsamples%2FWebflowReturnPage.php

`&ipnNotificationUrl` is set

Comment: Have you tried submitting from the [IPN simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator)?

Answer (score 3):

## Setting Up IPN Notifications on PayPal:

1. Click `Profile` on the `My Account tab`.
2. Click `Instant Payment Notification Preferences` in the `Selling Preferences` column.
3. Click `Choose IPN Settings` to specify your listener's URL and activate the listener. The following screen appears:

[image]

4. Specify the URL for your listener in the `Notification URL field`.
5. Click `Receive IPN messages (Enabled)` to enable your listener.
6. Click `Save`. The following screen appears:

[image]

7. Click `Back to Profile Summary` to return to the Profile after activating your listener. You also can click Edit settings to modify your notification URL or disable your listener. You can click Turn Off IPN to reset your IPN preferences.

---

## Dynamically Setting the Notification URL

You can specify an IPN listener for a specific payment; this is the only way to receive IPNs associated with Adaptive Payments. In this case, PayPal sends the IPN message to the listener specified in the notification URL for a specific button or API operation instead of the listener specified in your Profile.

To specify a notification URL For a/an :

1. PayPal Payments Standard button:

   `notify_url` HTML form variable
2. NVP API operation:
   `NOTIFYURL` field of the `DoDirectPayment`, `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`, or `DoReferenceTransaction` request.
3. SOAP API operation:

   `NotifyURL` field of the `DoDirectPayment`, `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`, or `DoReferenceTransaction` request.
4. Adaptive Payments API operation:
   `ipnNotificationUrl` field of the `Pay` or `Preapproval` request

---

Source:

[Identifying Your IPN Listener to PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/)